# Delete Data conversion but still has copy of the column

Tags: ssis, data-conversion

I have a data type mismatch problem and I was using SSIS data conversion to convert the data type.

But recently I find out I get the permission to  alter the table so I don't want to do the data conversion.

I went back the package and tried to delete the data conversion. Then I found out the data conversion left the "copy of column" name on it. and seems like the original column name is disappeared.

Now when I query my source table in ssms. It shows "Invalid column name".

- First I was wondering how I can make it right.(Besides to roll back to the previous version. )
- Second I would like to know why this is happening (delete the data conversion but left the altered column name here),
- Third I would like to know why I "select top 1000 rows" but shows "Invalid column name". That is very funny to me.

I tried to put "Copy of " in front of the column. That didn't work.

Comment: You need to refresh the meta data for the source.

Comment: Hi Brad: Thank you very much. Do you have any idea why is that happen? Could you please refer me one good book about ssis? I got so many choices. Also I watched some on YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have enough information to address all your questions but I'll take a swipe.

1. There is likely a visual indicator on the data flow path between the parent and grandchild transformations (where the data conversion sat) that being double clicked will show a dialogue indicating columns that no longer exist (right half of the popup). You want the option that is "delete unmapped references" or something to that effect.
2. Removed Component from Data Flow but new column name still visible - something has a reference to it and SSIS wants you to resolve this.
3. Invalid column name in SSMS, we'd have to see the query + the table(s) definition(s).